# Can't add Preference in ICS

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, preferences

How to add Preference in ICS using `addPreferencesFromResource()?` 
It is shown deprecated in ics. i've added a preference layout in xml folder.. but this could not be  added to the Preference activity..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From HC/ICS onward you should use [`PreferenceFragment.addPreferencesFromResource()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html#addPreferencesFromResource%28int%29) instead of [`Activity.addPreferencesFromResource()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html#addPreferencesFromResource%28int%29). However, this does require you switch how your preference code is structured - moving from an old style `PreferenceActivity` which directly adds the preferences to a new style `PreferenceActivity` that loads [PreferenceFragments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html) that then load the preferences. For an example of the new way, see the code sample in the [`PreferenceActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) docs.

Note that the [support library](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html) does not PreferenceFragment for backward compatibility pre-HC.